# How to work with file_get_contents for m3u8 file?

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP code that sends 3 GET Requests, one after the other

The purpose of the code is to get the content from the m3u8 file,

But in the last GET Request I get an error.

PHP:

```
<?php

//1. Create a proper token for the m3u8 to work
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Referer: http://www.hotstar.com",
      "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://www.hotstar.com/get_cdn_token.php";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$values = json_decode($data, true);
$url = $values['token'];

//2. Send another GET request along with the token, to pull the master m3u8
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Referer: http://www.hotstar.com",
      "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "https://secure-getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?hotstarauth=$url&action=GetCDN&appVersion=5.0.40&asJson=Y&channel=TABLET&id=1000055355&type=VOD";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$values = json_decode($data, true);
$link = $values['resultObj']['src'];

//3. Get the m3u8 content
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "$link";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

Through Inspect Element I accept the result:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=241000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_1_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=461000,RESOLUTION=416x234,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=861000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_3_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1360000,RESOLUTION=720x404,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_4_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2060000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_5_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3060000,RESOLUTION=1600x900,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_6_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4562000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_7_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgC0lfI2aGb2DFFZW1pBPartIAq++S+ee++3UM8jU49rfzGeMpTl2IaWB4PCyZ0c2yGZOtSqAhal4g%3d%3d
```

Through PHP I get the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1365/1000055355_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1515937603~exp=1515938203~acl=/*~hmac=c5f9294a198233a9751edbca51631c9cb12db63a08a69499c20d1208bd07aca8): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in **** on line 37
```

How do I arrange this please?

Comment: Your request is forbidden, this can be bypassed by changing the user agent, but to this you had to use php-curl, or the shell.

Comment: @Cryptopat But I've already added the user agent: 'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0" Maybe something else in the code is not good?

Comment: Well, we can't be sure this need to investigate this way. The fact is this file is accessible by your browser but not by your server. Why not just wget this file and use it locally, with regular updates.

Comment: @Cryptopat Inside the m3u8 file has links to all sorts of qualities, I wanted to pull the link to a 720p quality video. wget also good, if I can not fix, I'll use wget

Comment: The file is 403 for me, there is no luck^ This file needs a special cookie (login) to get access. You can set cookies with php-curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file needs a login to be accessed, for that you need a cookie mechanism on your file. This can be done with php-curl, or with curl alone in the shell.

Here is a php-curl snippet that can help you on this case.

There is more to do with curl. Anyway, the system needs an additional php package for this to works.

**sudo apt install php-curl**

```
$handle = curl_init();
$url = "https//lalala.com/file/files/oups.m3u";
$domain = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "", $url );
$header = array('Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0.1');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$result = curl_exec($handle);
var_dump($result);
```

See https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERAGENT.html for more details about php-curl.
See https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIE.html for how to setup cookies.

Comment: Add also a cookie and cookie_jar

Comment: I got into a bit of trouble with the installation of curl, because I'm with a Windows server, but fine now. I checked the code now and this is the result: bool(false). The request is generally sent without cookies, I also tried with. But it does not work out:(

Comment: I think I understood what the problem is >< proxy! Need to add proxy of India. They block requests outside of India. I'll check right away